# NuGet gives me an error when accessing server

Tags: nuget, http-status-code-502

We have set up a small NuGet server in our corporate network. It works fine for EVRYONE except me ;-)
When I try to list the available packages in Visual Studio, all I get is this error message:

> Unable to load the service index for source (...).
>   An error occurre while sending the request.
>   The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.

I've been struggeling with this issue for hours without success. Can anyone give me a hint on why this error occurs?

Comment: I have this error (502) when I try to publish the package . Did you solve the error ?

Comment: I also have the same error when I try to search the package with nuget manager 